# Why does an awk field assignment lose the output field separator?

Tags: awk

This command works.  It outputs the field separator (in this case, a comma):

```
$ echo "hi,ho"|awk -F, '/hi/{print $0}'
hi,ho
```

This command has strange output (it is missing the comma):

```
$ echo "hi,ho"|awk -F, '/hi/{$2="low";print $0}'
hi low
```

Setting the `OFS` (output field separator) variable to a comma fixes this case, but it really does not explain this behaviour.

Can I tell `awk` to keep the OFS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you modify the line (`$0`) `awk` re-constructs all columns and puts the value of `OFS` between them which by default is **space**. You modified the value of `$2` which means you forced `awk` to re-evaluate`$0`.

When you print the line as is using `$0` in your first case, since you did not modify any fields, `awk` did not re-evaluated each field and hence the field separator is preserved.

In order to preserve the field separator, you can specify that using:

**`BEGIN` block:**

```
$ echo "hi,ho" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}/hi/{$2="low";print $0}'
hi,low
```

**Using `-v` option:**

```
$ echo "hi,ho" | awk -F, -v OFS="," '/hi/{$2="low";print $0}'
hi,low
```

**Defining at the end of `awk`:**

```
$ echo "hi,ho" | awk -F, '/hi/{$2="low";print $0}' OFS=","
hi,low
```

Comment: Oh to go back in time and have `FS` mean both input and output "Field Separator" and have separate `IFS` and `OFS` variables for those rare cases when you want to set Input and Output Field Separators individually. Oh well.... +1.

Answer (score 1):

You first example does not change anything, so all is printed out as the input.
In second example, it change the line and it will use the default OFS, that is  (one space)
So to overcome this:

```
echo "hi,ho"|awk -F, '/hi/{$2="low";print $0}' OFS="," 
hi,low
```

Answer (score 0):

In your BEGIN action, set OFS = FS.

Comment: Normally you would not do `-F, 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} ..`, but `'BEGIN {OFS=FS=","} ..`