# Win7/GAWK .csv in .txt - Error Chinese Signs in Output and OFS not working

Tags: csv, fs

I'm using GAWK on Windows 7 PC to manipulate some txt-files and I'm totally newbie.
Currently I have several .csv-files that I want to merge together.
My .csv-files are separated by "\t" but I need that with ";".
So far GAWK recognizes the FS as "\t" but doesn't output the files with a ";" separator plus at the end of each line there are several "Chinese Signs" like "਍㄀嘀圀䈀匀㜀䄀㌀㄀䔀䌀".

Code-Line in Windows CMD:

```
gawk -v FS="\t" -v OFS=";" "{print $1$2}" test.csv > test.txt
```

I converted the .csv in .txt as well, had a look at it (tab separated) and used the .txt as input for my AWK:

```
gawk -v FS="\t" -v OFS=";" "{print $1$2}" test.txt
```

and had a look directly in CMD. No chinese signs but the columns are not separated by ";".

So far I'm just finding post/threads/documents about AWK/GAWK using on LINUX but none for Windows. I know that the functions are the same but the quoting is different. Maybe some of you has some tips for it?
I'm using GAWK with binaries of GnuWIN32 found [Here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm).

Maybe some of you can help with my two problems?

Comment: just in case... have you tried specifying `OFS` without quotes?

Comment: Yep. I tried OFS=; OFS; OFS=";" OFS";" ... I also tried without -v for FS and OFS or without "=". Nothing is working

Comment: Uh, yeah. `print $1$2` doesn't output any separator, because you don't tell it to. Consecutive operands with no comma between them are simply concatenated with nothing extra. Put a `,` between the fields, where you want `OFS` to appear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintaining the separator in awk output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178586/maintaining-the-separator-in-awk-output)

Comment: You're right. I have no idea why I forgot the ",". Thanks a lot for your help. It has to be like this: gawk -v F="\t" -v OFS=";" "{print $1,$2}" Test.txt

Comment: Wait: Output for $1,$2 works fine but not for $0 o0. Neither {print} is working with ";" OFS. Same tab separator like before :/

Comment: Please show some exact output, with a few lines showing that problem; the current description is unclear. It's probably an encoding issue but hard to say. As for `$0`, that's a well-known gotcha with `awk`; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479519/why-does-an-awk-field-assignment-lose-the-output-field-separator / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20844666/setting-the-output-field-separator-in-awk

Comment: `ID;Name;Package;PackageName;Function;FunctionName;AddOns਍㄀ <br/>
1;Karl;EL2;Standard;BX5;High;FirstclassPackage਍㄀     <br/>
2;Timo;EL2;Extended;BS1;Standard;None਍圀`